# Getting top 3 highest values in arraylist?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, integer, comparison

I have an arraylist filled with integers. I just need a way to get the top three integers in the arraylist.

Comment: From the answers received it is clear that there are two interpretations of your question. Do you want the first 3 items, or the 3 largest items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
List<Integer> list;
Collections.sort(list);
List<Integer> top3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.subList(Math.max(list.size() - 3, 0), list.size()));
```

I could have simply used the subList, but the list returned from subList() is a *view* on the base list, so changes made there would be reflected in top3.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own comparator and use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` on your `ArrayList`, which will bring the top 3 integers to the top(this is purely based on the logic in your comparator).

Comment: Well, that's up to the OP. Even if he does a sublist, he will still have to traverse through the list to get them. Instead he could just traverse the sorted list, till the 3rd position and get the values! IMHO, we should leave that part to the OP!

Comment: Looking at the question & the tags, I feel this is more about sorting the list, than anything else!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the list and what performance you want. If the list is "small" then any of the earlier solutions will suffice, depending on your requirements.

If the list is "large" and performance is important, then you should iterate through the list and keep the 3 largest as you go.

Another trade-off is your time and bugs vs using libraries. An of the library approaches mentioned will work in less of your programmer-time than a custom-coded solution

Answer (score 0):

use Collections.sort to sort and retrieve the first three values

Answer (score 0):

Put all the elements into a `TreeSet` using `TreeSet(Collection c)` constructor then use `TreeSet.descendingIterator` to get the first 3 elements. A list may contain duplicates,  using TreeSet guarantees that you retrieve 3 distinct largest values.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [List#subList(int fromIndex,int toIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29)

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

```
yourList.subList(yourList.size() -n, yourList.size());
```

As per sublist docs